# CSS - Set text-align of inline-element

Tags: css, alignment, center, inline

I have navigation points with text in it (longer and shorter). The text should be centered, but the text itself is aligned left; complicated to explain. Please have a look at my picture:

[image]

The upper three are my is-state but the lower three the should-be-state.

With `display: inline` my elements have the correct size (even with word breaks). So I gave the parent `text-align: center` to center the text-container horizontally. **But**: the text within the container should have `text-align: left`. But with `display: inline` this is not possible.

BTW: `display: inline-block` is not a solution because it strechs the container with longer text to 100% width even if the broken text does not fit.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/z5jo64bj/

Is there a way **without JavaScript** to solve this?

Comment: Put `text-align:left` on `nav#withInline a > span > span > span {`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/z5jo64bj/1/

Comment: But I want the text-container to be centered.